# Relaunch login activity as first activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have login activity which is launcher of my app

when user logs in I'm finishing this activity

But when users session expires I need to relaunch this activity and clear stack of activities

Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP works only if i'm not fifnishing login activity

what should i do to get needed functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use combination of flags:
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

And specify at the manifest new affinity for your LaunchActivity, e.g.:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity"  android:taskAffinity=".Main"/>
```

In this case task should be completely relaunched. And notice that you can use ApplicationContext to relaunch task.